# How do I prevent my Elixir pod in Kubernetes from getting taken down while I have in flight HTTP requests

Tags: kubernetes, elixir, google-kubernetes-engine, phoenix-framework

We have some payment endpoints in our Phoenix app that have a timeout of 153 seconds. These wrap around CardConnect Bolt API endpoints which require a very long timeout.

Having payment endpoints interrupted can lead to double charge and we'd like to avoid that if possible.

I think there is two parts to this.

1. Stop GKE from sending new requests to pods running old images once I have one pod with the new image deployed
2. Keep the old pod alive until 153 seconds has passed to let all these payment endpoints finish there work.

#1 is probably a Kubernetes configuration, and #2 might be Kubernetes and phoenix configuration.

The only thing that I've seen to partially address this is the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` for the pod https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#podspec-v1-core.

This seems like a common problem, but searching documentation hasn't yielded much for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes has Services. Services have selectors that are used to match pods. The matching record is stored as an `Endpoint`. What you're describe is possible. Let's see if we can get the requirement together:

1. You need to ensure K8s brings up the new pod before shutting this one down.
2. You need to ensure that K8s has probes to check when the new one can start serving connections (then it will be added to the `Endpoint` object and remove the old one). Removing it from the Endpoint does not break open TCP connections. It just stops new ones from going to the old pod.
3. You need to allow the running pod enough time to finish in-flight request BEFORE starting to shutdown.
4. You need to allow Kubernetes to kill the pod if it exceeds the in-flight time plus a generous shutdown time.

Now onto the YAML

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: web
  selector:
    app: web-app
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: web-app
  name: web-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: web-app
          lifecycle:
            # This "sleep" preStop hook delays the
            # Pod shutdown 
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/sleep
                  - "154" # The max timeout for in flight requests + plus 1 second
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 3
            failureThreshold: 3
            successThreshold: 1
            httpGet:
              port: web
              path: /
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            httpGet:
              port: web
              path: /
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: web
              protocol: TCP
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 155  # sleep period plus the shutdown time
```

Try this out and see if it works for you.

Comment: That's interesting. It seems like the `lifecycle` method `stop` is the piece that is actually going to make this work. Right? 
Do the `rollingUpdate` percentages matter here?

Comment: Hi there. Yeah they do. They ensure that a new pod is started and healthy before the old one is taken down.

Comment: I don't know what your yaml looks like right now but I've seen some cases where a person's new pod is being stopped before the new one is started.  If you want there to be some pod to answer the calls to they endpoint then you're going to want to do something similar to the rolling update I've suggested. Play with it and watch the `Endpoint` value live and see the pod IPs as the new one gets ready and replaced the existing one. I might also not fully grasp the requirement.